# Is there a way to check if a memory address is between two other addresses?

Tags: c++, pointers, iteration, memory-address

Let's say that, "hypothetically", I had this code:

```cpp
//two separate arrays of the same object that for the purposes of this question we will assume are not adjacent in memory
ObjectName* m_objects0 = new ObjectName[10];
ObjectName* m_objects1 = new ObjectName[10];

//and a pointer to a single object
ObjectName* m_pObject = nullptr;
```

If I wanted to iterate over every object in `m_objects0` until I reached the end, then "jump" to the start of `m_objects1` to iterate over it, how would I check if the address of `m_pObject` sits between the start and end addresses of either array? (my only info being the start and end addresses of each array) Is it even feasible?

The only way I can think of accomplishing it is to somehow convert an address to an `int`.

Comment: Except for equality/inequality, you can only compare pointers with pointers to elements in the same array or members of the same class. So either your comparison shows the pointer is within the bounds of the array, or it has UB. You could compare your pointer with every element in one of the arrays, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: What is the high-level goal you are trying to accomplish?  This is sounding like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Also, why are you comparing low-level things like pointer addresses?  A good design compares whether some attribute of an object is the same or exists in a container of objects, not explicitly compare pointer addresses to see if that address "falls between" two addresses.

Comment: _"how would I check if the address of `m_pObject` sits between the start and end addresses of either array"_ it isn't, because it's null.  Or it isn't, because it's a local variable.  Depending on what you mean by "address of `m_pObject`".  This "hypothetical" scenario may be obfuscating the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can't.   The `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` operators on pointers have undefined behaviour unless both pointers point to elements of the same array, or members of the same structure.   The most you can do is check if `m_pObject` points at an element of `m_objects0` or it points at an element of `m_objects1`.   If it doesn't point at an element of either, that's it - there is no way (without invoking undefined behaviour) to test if it it points "between" your arrays, "before" both of them, or "after" both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a given pointer is (in)equal to any other pointer using the `==` and `!=` operators.

However, you can check if a given pointer is `<(=)` or `>(=)` another pointer *only* when both pointers are pointing within the same object/array, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

So, while `m_pObject` is pointing at an element in `m_objects0`, you can't check if it is (not) pointing at an element in `m_objects1` using address ranges.

However, you can do something like this instead:

```cpp
ObjectName* m_objects0 = new ObjectName[10];
ObjectName* m_objects1 = new ObjectName[10];

...

ObjectName* object_ptrs[] = {
    m_objects0, m_objects0 + 10,
    m_objects1, m_objects1 + 10
};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i += 2)
{
    ObjectName* m_pObject = object_ptrs[i];
    ObjectName* m_pObjects_end = object_ptrs[i+1];

    while (m_pObject != m_pObjects_end)
    {
        ...
        ++m_pObject;
    }
}

...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2deESn)

Which, you could generalize a bit further (ie, if you needed more than 2 arrays) using something this instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

ObjectName* m_objects0 = new ObjectName[10];
ObjectName* m_objects1 = new ObjectName[10];
...

std::vector<std::pair<ObjectName*,ObjectName*>> object_ptrs;
object_ptrs.emplace_back(m_objects0, m_objects0 + 10);
object_ptrs.emplace_back(m_objects1, m_objects1 + 10);
...

for(auto &p : object_ptrs)
{
    ObjectName* m_pObject = p.first;
    ObjectName* m_pObjects_end = p.second;

    while (m_pObject != m_pObjects_end)
    {
        ...
        ++m_pObject;
    }
}

...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/myEwL5)